# What's a Pythonic way of taking a list of lists and "distributing" elements from another list to the sublists?

Tags: python, list, append

I've been trying to learn some Python for just under two weeks now. So, sorry if I'm just completely misinformed.

I've been searching for about five days as I've been learning the language for the answer to this question, and the wording is difficult for me to articulate, so if I missed it please feel free to mark this as duplicate and point me in the right direction.

Let's say I have `list1 = [[x, y], [a, b]]` and `list2 = [0, 1]`.

I want `list3 = [[x, y, 0], [x, y, 1], [a, b, 0], [a, b, 1]]`

In my research here on StackOverflow and experimenting on my own I've found ways to get all sorts of similar results like:

`[[x, y, 0], [a, b, 1]]`

`[[x, y, 0, 1], [a, b, 0, 1]]`

`[[x, y, 0, 1], [a, b]]`

`[[[x, y], 0], [[x, y], 1], [[a, b], 0], [[a, b], 1]]`

The thing that I've been considering would be to do something like the following:

1. Create as many iterations of the sublists in list1 are there are
   elements in list2 
   `[[x, y], [a, b]] -> [[x, y], [x, y], [a, b], [a, b]]`
2. Flatten list1 so that it's no longer sublists, but repeating
   elements `[[x, y], [x, y], [a, b], [a, b]] -> [x, y, x, y, a, b, a, b]`
3. Go through the elements of list1 and insert the elements of
   list2 along the flattened list `[x, y, x, y, a, b, a, b] -> [x, y, 0, x, y, 1, a, b, 0, a, b, 1]`
4. Group the elements into the
   appropriate size: 
   `[x, y, 0, x, y, 1, a, b, 0, a, b, 1] -> [[x, y, 0], [x, y, 1], [a, b, 0], [a, b, 1]]`

If that's what I have to do, then that's what I have to do, and I am looking for a way to do it that way, but I feel like there must be some sort of more-Pythonic way of doing this operation (then again, what do I know?) and, if so, I'm struggling to find out what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its heart, this is just a cross product of the two lists.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
[(['x', 'y'], 0), (['x', 'y'], 1), (['a', 'b'], 0), (['a', 'b'], 1)]
```

All that's left to do is to flatten each tuple.

```
>>> [x + [y] for x,y in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
[['x', 'y', 0], ['x', 'y', 1], ['a', 'b', 0], ['a', 'b', 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. In itertools, I had only looked at and tried cycle and was having no luck there, and I haven't seen that particular construction of flattening tuples inside of a list before.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but theres not a great itertools solution i dont think

```
def permutations(a,b):
    for sublist in a:
        for value in b:
            yield sublist + [value]

list1 = [[x, y], [a, b]] 
list2 = [0, 1]
print(list(permutations(list1, list2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just a list comprehension:

```
list3 = [list[:] + [elem] for list in list1 for elem in list2]
```

Comment: The code you've listed here doesn't provide the behavior I'm looking for. This generated, using my example: [ [ [x, y], [a, b], 0],  [ [x, y], [a, b], 1],  [ [x, y], [a, b], 0],  [ [x, y], [a, b], 1]]

Comment: That code (copied and pasted) gives me exactly what you're looking for. Perhaps a typing error?

Comment: I copied and pasted as well. If I edited it to be [list + [elem] for list in list1 for elem in list2], then it worked, but list[:] gave me the answer I commented above. Good to know there's a plain list comprehension for it, though!

EDIT: Oh, nevermind! You were right; when I copied and pasted it to play with it, I didn't change the keyword list to be something else. Changing it to list_[:] + [elem] for list_ ... did the trick.

Comment: Glad it's sorted. Although the 'list' keyword is override (overridden?) in the definition of the for loop, so should not matter. Also, using [:] or not would not change anything, since both return a copy of the list and the expression results in concatenation of the two lists. I suspect you had a populated 'list3' before running the comprehension. Otherwise i'll be a bit stumped!